# Changing WordPress blog URL structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have blog with structure
 `example.com/old-url/post-name`
I want change old URL with a new URL like

```
example.com/new-url/post-name
```

I can change the structure from WordPress but needs a redirect to keep the posts working. There are 1000+ blog posts.

I think .htaccess is the way to go. A wildcard redirect? Or any other approach?

Comment: "but needs a redirect to keep the posts working" - you mean to maintain SEO and keep inbound links from working? The redirect should not be necessary "to keep the posts working" when browsing the site (if it is then you've done something wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^old-url/(.*)$ /new-url/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This should take any URL that includes `old-url` and turn them into `new-url`. Including any sub-directories.

In the above I've set the `302` flag, this makes it a temporary redirect, once you know this is working as you expected then change it to `301` which is a permanent redirect.

So for example:

`example.com/old-url/post-name` will become `example.com/new-url/post-name`